# Test React Hook In Functional Component Using Sinon and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, enzyme, sinon

I am trying to write unit tests with mocha, sinon, and enzyme to cover the following component:

```
    import useCustomHook from './useCustomHook';

    const TestComponent = () => {
        const { data, error } = useCustomHook();

        if (error) {
            return <div id="test-component-error">{error}</div>
        }

        return (
            <select>
                {data.map((record) => <option>{record.name}</option>}
            </select>
        )
    }
```

I cannot figure out how to mock this custom hook using sinon in order to have sample `data` and `error` values to test all possible paths through the UI.

```
    const useCustomHook = () => {
        const [data, setData] = useState([]);
        const [error, setError] = useState(null);

        const getData = () => new Service().getData().then((results) => {
            setData(results);
        }).catch((err) => {
            setError(err);
        });

        useEffect(() => {
            getData();
        }, []);

        return { data, error };
    }
```

This test fails:

```
    describe(<TestComponent />, () => {
        it('renders an error when receiving one from hook', () => {
            const stub = sinon.stub(TestComponent, 'useCustomHook')
                .returns({ data: [], error: 'test error' });
            const wrapper = mount(<TestComponent />);
            expect(wrapper.find('#test-component-error')
                .to.have.length(1)
        });
    })
```

Have tried several other variations of `stub`, `spy`, and `fake` and have not been able to successfully get values into `TestComponent`.

Comment: Your question isn't internally consistent - do you want to test the hook, or mock it out for tests of a consumer of it? Either way, what have you done so far?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added a bit more detail.  I'd like to mock it out for tests of a consumer of it.  I have the hook fully tested successfully.